# Alamofire - asymmetric cryptography with elliptic curve key (SSL pinning)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, pinning

I have a problem with connecting to server using Alamofire.

I use this code (credits to cnoon):

```
class NetworkManager {    
    public static var manager : Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        // Create the server trust policies
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "my.server.example.com/api": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            )
        ]
        // Create custom manager
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
        let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(
            configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
        return man
    }()
}
```

And I have these certificates which I converted to .der format:

```
client.cert.der
ca.cert.der
```

And I have also this file with key - it is not a certificate, only the key:
client.key.pem

The content of file is (example):

```
-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
AxxrtknPQXGLw==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
HFDHJBJDB7asjqojhJhhfehiHguegufbBIWhgfbibIUBbf+Hhifhie87nbGrztOIUb
giGiGIGgzfwtUZTuio+hifegfiIUwzzUG768+HhifeihiI546banneeoPJnkienivbiBIFW
HkGVi7d/HJihgfegui876gvejfbGUv/Zb7867798g
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So the question is, how can I connect to the server using these two certificates, the key and Alamofire (if Alamofire cant use it, then it is not mandatory).

EDIT:
This is the response:

> 2017-08-26 12:26:31.351511+0200 TestAppO2[79217:6915260] []
>   nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke_3
>   tls_handshake_continue: [-9812] 2017-08-26 12:26:31.351
>   TestAppO2[79217:6915379] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) Response: nil
>   Alamofire.DefaultDataResponse(request:
>   Optional(https://my.server.example.com/api), response: nil, data:
>   Optional(0 bytes), error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be
>   connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “https://my.server.example.com” which could put your confidential
>   information at risk."
>   UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to
>   connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
>       ""

Comment: You need to redact a URL in your error message. But in any case, is the certificate for that stage domain or the normal production one? Also, you don't need the `/api` in the pinning setup.

Comment: @JonShier You are right, the /api was redundant. Not it returns 400 Bad certificate, which is good, actually. Maybe I should merge client certificate and client key?